# Shared DB Instance with FastAPI Routers

Tags: python, fastapi, circular-dependency

So, in my project I have a main.py (app/main.py) which is where my FastAPI app resides.
Then I have additional router(s) in app/routers/test_router.py.

What I want is once, when the app is initialized by uvicorn to establish a database connection, and then I can use that database connection across all my router(s).

However, because I need to import the router file's APIRouter variable into the main.py file, the main.py depends on the test_router.py file.

But, if I wanted to import main.py's db_instance variable into my router, then my router file would depend on main.py, creating a circular dependency.

Main.py:

```
import fastapi

from fastapi import FastAPI
from app.routers.test_router import router
app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)

some_db_instance = "Initiate DB Instance once on App startup."
@app.get("/", include_in_schema=False)
async def root():
    return fastapi.responses.RedirectResponse("/docs")
```

test_router.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from app.main import some_db_instance
router = APIRouter(prefix="/test", tags=["Test"])


@router.get("/data")
async def get_test():
    do_stuff_with_db = some_db_instance + "..."
    return "Hello World"
```

I have workarounds, I am just not satisfied that it is the correct/good way.

So, what is a good/pythonic way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: In FastAPI you usually do this with a dependency through `Depends`, as shown in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/ and https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/ - also be aware that having a single connection might give you issues with concurrency when more than a single client is connecting to your API at the time (which is why there's usually a connection pool involved)